# mount glusterfs before nginx start after reboot

Tags: nginx, centos7, glusterfs

On Centos 7 after reboot

How can I make sure NGINX is only started after the glusterFS mount is completed?

I tried adding a line to rc.local but nginx fails to start and the directory is not mounted at all after reboot. This is the mount command.

`/usr/sbin/mount.glusterfs localhost:/Replicatedvolume /home -o direct-io-mode=enable`

which works when I run it manually and then start nginx/

thank you

Comment: Why are you mounting in rc.local?!?

Comment: to make it work after reboot automatically? What kind of question is that

Comment: It's a serious question. You're supposed to put it in `/etc/fstab` like every other mount. You didn't explain why you chose not to follow [the directions](https://docs.gluster.org/en/latest/Administrator%20Guide/Setting%20Up%20Clients/#auto-mount).

Answer (score -1):

In case someone wonders, I had to put "sleep 5" before the mount command in rc.local

Might be working with less seconds but sleep 1 had no effect.

I also added service nginx start to the rc.local script below the mount and it now works.